# How to prevent processor state from automatically changing to 100%?

Tags: windows-7, cpu

I like to slightly under-clock my processor to keep it cool. I use the following setting :
[image]
But while playing games(usually for 4-5 minutes) the settings automatically jump back to 100%.
[image]
I have also tried making a new power plan but same thing happens. My processor is Amd anthlon X2 4600(2.4 GHz) and OS is Windows 7.

Why is processor state automatically changing and how to prevent it ?

Comment: Try using the *Power Saver* profile.

Comment: @James Tried that already. Same behavior, both processor sates jumping back to 100%.

Comment: Do you have the Catalyst control centre installed?  Try closing it. Someone else had a similar problem: http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-performance-maintenance/180652-power-options-keeps-resetting-upon-startup.html

Comment: @James It is working for now. Please post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody else reported a similar issue and it seems that it was caused by the ATI/AMD Catalyst Control Panel. Closing it and removing it from startup might fix the problem.

Source: http://www.vistaheads.com/forums/microsoft-public-windows-vista-performance-maintenance/180652-power-options-keeps-resetting-upon-startup.html

Comment: Thanks. This fixed the problem, but I don't understand why all of a sudden catalyst started causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im not really sure, but I think that means that's using the 100% of the 85% of your assigned processing power.

Comment: +1 for that; if these settings are configured in BIOS then Windows might not know they exist.

Comment: @Rhyuk I think you have misunderstood . I am not taking about processor usage. I have made it clearer now. please re-read.

Comment: @jackweirdy Cool and quite is enabled in BIOS so the processor can run at different states. Btw the settings were working fine till now.

Comment: My bad, work firewall is blocking images. Thought this was BIOS configured.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/power4gear-hybrid-keeps-resetting-itself-to-100-minimum-processor-state.695129/) thread, this could also be caused by ASUS touchpad program. For my device(ASUS T300 Chi with Windows 10), importing the following [task](http://pastebin.com/mgZbVE39):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.4" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  <RegistrationInfo>
    <Date>2013-09-24T21:40:06.4839126</Date>
    <Author>DuctTapeDude</Author>
    <Description>Combats 100% Minimum CPU use from the Asus Smart Gesture thing</Description>
  </RegistrationInfo>
  <Triggers>
    <EventTrigger>
      <Enabled>true</Enabled>
      <Subscription>&lt;QueryList&gt;&lt;Query Id="0" Path="System"&gt;&lt;Select Path="System"&gt;*[System[Provider[@Name='Microsoft-Windows-UserModePowerService'] and (Level=4 or Level=0) and Task = 10 and (EventID=12) and Security[@UserID='S-1-5-18']]]&lt;/Select&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/QueryList&gt;</Subscription>
    </EventTrigger>
  </Triggers>
  <Principals>
    <Principal id="Author">
      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>
      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>
    </Principal>
  </Principals>
  <Settings>
    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>
    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>
    <StopIfGoingOnBatteries>true</StopIfGoingOnBatteries>
    <AllowHardTerminate>false</AllowHardTerminate>
    <StartWhenAvailable>false</StartWhenAvailable>
    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>
    <IdleSettings>
      <StopOnIdleEnd>true</StopOnIdleEnd>
      <RestartOnIdle>false</RestartOnIdle>
    </IdleSettings>
    <AllowStartOnDemand>true</AllowStartOnDemand>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <Hidden>true</Hidden>
    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>
    <DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>false</DisallowStartOnRemoteAppSession>
    <UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>false</UseUnifiedSchedulingEngine>
    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>
    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT5S</ExecutionTimeLimit>
    <Priority>7</Priority>
  </Settings>
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMIN 0</Arguments>
    </Exec>
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/SETACVALUEINDEX SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR PROCTHROTTLEMIN 4</Arguments>
    </Exec>
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_BALANCED SUB_PROCESSOR SYSCOOLPOL 0</Arguments>
    </Exec>
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\Windows\System32\powercfg.exe</Command>
      <Arguments>/SETDCVALUEINDEX SCHEME_BALANCED 44f3beca-a7c0-460e-9df2-bb8b99e0cba6 3619c3f2-afb2-4afc-b0e9-e7fef372de36 0</Arguments>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

provided in [this](http://forum.notebookreview.com/threads/lower-zenbook-power-consumption-due-to-asus-smart-gesture.741039/) thread seems to have it fixed for me.