# Asus Smart Gesture getting CPU to 3GHz

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

I bought a new Asus Ux303ln laptop and the touchpad drivers (asus smart gesture) gets the cpu frequency up to 3GHz everytime I scroll with 2 fingers. This seems to be using alot of power and I only get about 4 hours of battery life while browsing the web.

I have tried updating the drivers to a newer version I found on [Asus website](http://www.asus.com/Notebooks_Ultrabooks/ASUS_ZENBOOK_UX303LN/HelpDesk_Download/), version 3.012 but it still has the same problem. Since I don't know for certain which brand of touchpad I have on this laptop (the windows device manager calls it "ASUS touchpad"), I have tried both synaptics and Elantech drivers, but neither one of them will install.

I have also tried to limit the CPU's maximum speed at power settings to 99% but once I scroll it seems to reset to 100%...

Does anyone know how to block Asus smart gesture from getting my cpu to 3Ghz? Or if there is anyway to install a better driver, the only gesture I need is 2 finger scrolling.

Thank you!

Comment: You can uninstall the software.  Honestly though its unlikely going to extend your battery life by any measureable amount.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a DWORD value with Regedit to disable that behaviour:

In `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ASUS\ASUS Smart Gesture`

Add the `DWORD AutoSetMaxPower`, set it to `0` and reboot.

Comment: +1 My laptop fan was always running, this fixed it!

Comment: So what exactly does this do? And can you explain how it works?

Comment: It's a builtin feature of the driver, when it's enabled (and it is by default), it will set the CPU maximum speed to 100% whenever you scroll with the touchpad.
See there => https://www.geek.com/apps/asus-says-100-cpu-utilization-is-required-for-smooth-scrolling-on-laptops-1608457/
But maybe it's not relevant anymore today with the newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Why blocking the turbo mode of the CPU, let it boost, you are loosing performance.

Instead of crippling your CPU's performance by disabling it's turbo, I would advice you to uninstall that soft, and try a **newer** version of the "ASUS touchpad" software for a similar laptop (or an refresh model of it). It's probably a known bug and they will fix it soon.

My answer was correct as OP said he fixed it with a newer version.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but I resolved it by:

1. Uninstalling Asus smart gesture from windows 10
2. Reboot Windows
3. Download and installing drivers Version V11.5.16.2 from this site - http://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/589/0/21/41/
4. Reboot Windows
5. Go to System-->Device Manager-->Mouse and pointers-->Driver-->Update Driver
   Windows installed Asus Touchpad and Asus Smart Gesture.
6. Reboot Windows

From that moment I don't have problems with high CPU usage when scrolling

Answer (score 0):

This is a behavior that ASUS refused to change, according to [this](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8546702) post. One option is to use 3rd party touchpad drivers. For a temporary solution that resets the power management setting, you can see my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/968991/217651).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy (and overwrite) all file in folder:
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ASUS Smart Gesture\Win10_AP\x64"
to
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\ASUS\ASUS Smart Gesture\AsTPCenter\x64"

If explorer tells you that they are in use, go to taskbar and kill "ASUS Smart Gesture ...." tasks. The "Loader" task must be first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I fixed it this way.

- Uninstall the existing Asus Smart Gesture
- If you have an ELAN touchpad then first download and install the latest driver from this [link](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/589/0/21/41/)
- Download and install the latest Asus Smart Gesture from [here](https://www.asus.com/support/Download/3/569/0/3/45/).

Comment: links not working anymore :(

Answer (score 0):

For me what solve was uninstalling the Smart Gesture that windows installed 
automatically, FIRST installing from my notebook model ASUS site the ATK driver and THEN the most up-to-date ASUS Smart Gesture driver.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from here works fine:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/5b22401e-4cd0-498d-aa65-57fa49d12616/asus-smart-gesture-center-using-50-cpu-or-more-why?forum=w8itproperf

Just install "Remote Link"

1. Run Asus Smart Gesture
2. Go to Mobile Control
3. Install or activate Remote Link
4. Restart your computer.

I unexpectedly resolved the problem when I was about to connect my phone to the laptop using USB cable, the Asus Smart Gesture popped up. It suggests to install the Remote Link and then I tried. After restarting the computer I checked the CPU performance, the CPU performs just 5%.

Answer (score 0):

**2023**

I noticed this problem 11 years after buying my laptop. Amazing!
I read all other solutions. Here's what worked on my Asus K55VD:

1. Uninstall Asus Smart Gesture, then reboot
2. Uninstall ATK Package, then reboot
3. Install ATK package (ASUS Keyboard Hotkeys) version 1.0.00061, then reboot. This package was not in my laptop's support and downloads page. However, this post from Asus prompted ALL users of any ATK version to update to the latest version, so it gave me more confidence, regardless of my laptop's age. I grabbed it from [here](https://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10) after a simple search. Do a search online if the page is down.
4. Install Asus Smart Gesture V4.0.24 (driver only), then reboot. This was not in my laptop's support page either. I grabbed it from [here](https://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10) after a simple search. Do a search online if page is down.

Shoutout to IvanRF for his [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/952895/asus-atk-driver-for-windows-10) on where to find the silly latest ATK.