# Asus ATK driver for Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, drivers, touchpad, asus-laptop

I'm trying to search the ATK Package driver for Asus Notebooks suitable for Windows 10 but I can find only versions for previous Windows version (8, 8.1, 7). Have Asus already released their ATK driver for Win10?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

ASUS support site is not very user friendly .

I made a post with all the [ASUS drivers for Windows 10](https://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10/) , including ATK Package.

Here you can find [**ATK Package 1.0.0061**](https://ivanrf.com/en/latest-asus-drivers-for-windows-10/#atk-package), for 64-bit and 32-bit versions.

Comment: their file storage is down now, could anyone upload the package please?

Comment: @vorou sometimes the ASUS server is down, but you just need to wait a couple of minutes and try again

Comment: Hi, I landed here after a google search to fix hcontrol.exe using max CPU after upgrade to windows 10.  I tried your version and have the same problem.  Is there anything I can do?

Comment: This is exactly what fixed my dump touchpad from reaching 20% CPU usage. Installed this ATK, then the latest Smart Gesture from your page. You are doing God's work.

Answer (score 7):

Asus released an official ATK driver for Windows 10 64 bit and you can reach at this link (pointing to Asus official download support site):

http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/ATKPackage/ATKPackage_Win10_64_VER100039.zip

Answer (score 6):

Asus has a hard to find downloads section where you can grab latest versions of some apps and drivers.

Follow [this link](http://support.asus.com.cn/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=479&m=ATKpackage&os=36&ft=10) and click *Change Your Model*, a window will appear. Select *Notebook* in the left column and then **don't select your laptop model**. Between laptop models in the center column there are some interesting items:

- Apps
- Apps for Win8
- Apps for Win8.1
- Apps for Win10
- Drivers
- Drivers for Win8
- Drivers for Win8.1
- Drivers for Win10

Select one of these, then choose the app/driver you want from the right column. In this case you'll want to select *Apps for Win10*, then *ATKPackage* and click *Confirm*. Then switch to *Downloads* tab, select Windows 10 (32-bit or 64-bit, whichever you have), expand the ATK node and grab your installer.

[image: Screenshot from Asus website]

Other hard-to-find downloads can be found this way too.

Comment: They broke even that. It's almost like they don't want people using their products...

Comment: Yeah, it's a mess. You'd think they are more careful in the high price category of ultrabooks. Never gonna buy Asus notebooks again. But I am usually working on a workstation anyway.