# Winflash and ATK driver

Tags: drivers, bios, asus-laptop

I want to update my laptop's BIOS with Winflash on Windows10_64, because EZFlash can't update the same BIOS version. Winflash asks me for the ATK driver, then I installed it. But when I run Winflash again, it continues to ask me for the ATK driver - like it hasn't been installed.
I tried it with various versions, the links mostly taken from [this SU question](https://superuser.com/questions/952895/asus-atk-driver-for-windows-10).

Do you have any hints ?