# Screen doesnt react to to brigtness change

Tags: windows-10, intel-graphics

My screen doesnt change brightness any more since yesterday evening, when I press the corresponging button on the laptop. The brighntess bar shows up, but doesnt change anything.
What I tried so far:

- restart laptop
- check for driver updates using the windows device manager
- check for driver updates using the intel driver & support assistant

Here is a detailed [system report](https://drive.google.com/file/d/16yocw9XlF1wh-AcaKJZ4f7FIz_PECmmL/view?usp=sharing) with all the drivers, if that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed the latest graphics driver from my manufacturers website, in the case of Asus, these drivers can be found [here](https://www.asus.com/support/Download-Center/). I made shure to install the driver from my manufaturers website and not from the intel download center. Now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I would do in your case is to completely reformat your system, or reinstall the hotkey driver specific to your laptop, or install [ClickMonitorDDC](https://www.softpedia.com/get/System/System-Miscellaneous/ClickMonitorDDC.shtml) just make sure to use an adblocker when downloading the file though. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This feature requires a working ATK driver on Asus laptops. Unfortunately ASUS is notoriously bad at providing updates to it. Version 1.0.0061 is available [here](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/Apps_for_Win10/ATKPackage/ATK_Package_V100061.zip). Try to install it and reboot.

(I've found the link in [this question](https://superuser.com/a/991696/194694))